# Python : Unable to fix a bug in parsing a list

Tags: python, list

I have a python code which looks like this.

```
trades = self.get_trades(socket)  # returns a 2D list
print trades              #this prints the list
for trade in trades :
    print trade           # prints each row in list
```

The line `print trades` prints a 2d which actually looks like this

```
[['name_1_1_D', '150923000048067', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.
7], ['name_2_1_3', '150923000048824', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 3
5.8], ['name_3_1_M', '150923000049331', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0,
 36.55], ['name_4_1_E', '150923000049744', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25
, 0, 36.6], ['name_5_1_5', '150923000051339', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT',
25, 0, 40.4], ['name_6_1_Q', '150923000052013', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT
', 25, 0, 38.1]]
```

But while printing the individual List elements,the line inside a for loop `print trade` is printing a wrong element like this

```
['name_1_1_D', '150923000048067', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', '', 25, 0, 0.0]
```

The element 5th and 8th element of the list are been changed to '' and 0.0.

I am really not getting why is this thing happening and what part of my code is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: i ran this code in python 3. its displaying all values

Comment: And there are no other lines in between `print trades` and `for trade in trades: print trade` ?

Comment: Ya there are no other lines.

Comment: What python version you are using?

Comment: It works all fine. . I don't their is any problem with the code.. worked for python2.x also

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have any newline characters or other superfluous characters in that data coming from the socket?

Comment: Please provide us a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks for the replies and answers. This seems like problem of new line charecters in the data.

Answer (score 1):

Works fine in python 2.9.10 too:

```
trades = [['name_1_1_D', '150923000048067', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE','SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.7],
          ['name_2_1_3', '150923000048824', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 35.8],
          ['name_3_1_M', '150923000049331', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.55],
          ['name_4_1_E', '150923000049744', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25 , 0, 36.6],
          ['name_5_1_5', '150923000051339', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 40.4],
          ['name_6_1_Q', '150923000052013', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT ', 25, 0, 38.1]]

print trades

for trade in trades:
    print trade
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have newline characters in that stream of data coming from the socket.
Obviously, simply typing in your data and running the code, isn't going to replicate the situation that you have.
Test your data for superfluous characters within the data coming from the socket.

Comment: Thanks for the  answer. This seems like problem of new line charecters in the data.

Comment: If this answer did resolve the problem you could accept the answer and that will show the problem has been solved and give me a few points ;)

Answer (score 0):

It works fine under python 3.4.3:

Script `run.py`:

```
trades = [['name_1_1_D', '150923000048067', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.7], ['name_2_1_3', '150923000048824', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 35.8], ['name_3_1_M', '150923000049331', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.55], ['name_4_1_E', '150923000049744', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.6], ['name_5_1_5', '150923000051339', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT',25, 0, 40.4], ['name_6_1_Q', '150923000052013', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 38.1]]

for trade in trades:
    print(trade)
```

Exacution:

```
$ python run.py
['name_1_1_D', '150923000048067', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.7]
['name_2_1_3', '150923000048824', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 35.8]
['name_3_1_M', '150923000049331', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.55]
['name_4_1_E', '150923000049744', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 36.6]
['name_5_1_5', '150923000051339', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'BUY', 'MKT', 25, 0, 40.4]
['name_6_1_Q', '150923000052013', 'NIFTY15SEP7800CE', 'SELL', 'MKT', 25, 0, 38.1]
```